# Save method of Django model's instance does not update fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem with the save of a Django models' instance.

In my models.py, I have :

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=32,null=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

And, well, I just want to update an instance of it with new values. My views.py contains :

```
def updateThing(request):
    ...
    message = request.POST.get('thing').encode('utf-8')
    title = request.POST.get('title').encode('utf-8')
    thingId = int(request.POST.get('thingId'))

    item = Thing.objects.get(id=thingId)
    if item:
        if len(title) > 0:
            item.title = title
        item.message = message
        item.save()

        addToLog(request,"success update : " + message,False)
```

If I display the logs (added by addToLog method) after updateThing has been called, I can see the "success update", which means that the Thing instance had been found, the "message" (+ message) is the new one, but my instance still have old values stored : When I display them, the old message and title are displayed.

Since Django doesn't raise any exception, I suppose it's just a bad use of .save(), but I don't know what the problem is.

I need your help to understand and correct my code.

Thanks you

Comment: Do you have a custom save() method? Or pre_save or post_save?

Comment: No, I didn't override any methods I think

Comment: Does it help if you remove the .encode('utf-8') from the message and title assignments? It's unlikely you want to do that.

Comment: Why do you have your model in views.py file instead of models.py? If you are not importing it in models.py, that can cause improper behaviour of it.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to verify that the item's attributes have not changed. And what is the rest of that view?

Comment: I use .encode('utf-8') to avoid trouble with accents.

My model is in models.py, I edited the post.

I can see attributes have not changed when I display them, with :

things = Thing.objects.filter(kind=kindOfThing).order_by('-date','-id')
                    
return HttpResponse(render_to_string('manageThing.html',{'things':things,'kind':kindOfThing}))

Comment: Django handles encoding for you, you shouldn't set encoded bytestrings to `CharField`s. Also, your model definition does not include `message`. If that's not a just a typo, well, you can set any attribute you want on a model instance but if it's not in the model definition it won't persist.

Comment: And really you should be using a ModelForm to handle all this.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper that was not a typo... Thank you, it works now. Put it as an answer, I will accept it !

Comment: On a side note: `item = Thing.objects.get(id=thingId); if item:` is not the correct way to handle non-existing items. Use a try-catch block which catches the `django.db.models.ObjectDoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: And I'll take and think about all the advices you gave me, about encoding, item existence and ModelForm. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `message` field was missing from the model definition, so setting the value on the instance in the view updated an in-memory attribute but saving it did not persist it.