# django model does not save the uploaded image

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to upload/update images that users upload using django/ajax/jquery. my front-end code seems to be working. But the django model does not upload/save the passed image.

here is my profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{ self.user.username } Profile'
```

and the forms for updating the user info:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

and this is my view function for updating the image:

```
@login_required
def update_profile_image(request):
    #print(request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        print(p_form)

        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()

            context = {'None': 'none'}
            return JsonResponse(context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('None')
```

when I print the `p_form`, that is what it prints on the command window:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_image">Image:</label></th><td>Currently: <a href="/media/profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg">profile_pics/profile_pic.jpg</a><br>
Change:
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="id_image"></td></tr>
```

I have added `enctype="multipart/file-data"` to my form so that is not the problem.

and this my ajax call which as I said seems to be working fine:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#profile_edit_form', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();
  //method = $(this).attr('method');

  var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files[0];
  formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("img_data", img_data);
  console.log(formdata.get("img_data"));

  $.ajax({
      url     : "/users/update_profile_info/",
      type    : 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data    : $(this).serialize(),
      success : function(data) {

        $('#profile_name_tag').html(data.username);
        $('#username_navbar').html(data.username);



        $.ajax({
            url         : "/users/update_profile_image/",
            type        : 'POST',
            enctype     : "multipart/form-data",   //it is done inside jquery
            data        : formdata,
            cache       : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
              console.log('success');
              //$('#profile_picture').html(data.)

            },
            error: function(data) {
              console.log('image-fail');
            }
        });

      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log('info-fail');
      }
  });


});
```

I hope you guys can help. I am super lost. I have been struggling with this for days but still have no idea where the problems is.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the form is getting saved? The print statement happens before the `p_form.is_valid()` check.

Comment: @WillKeeling I printed it after the save and it shows the same thing on the command window. but apparently the form is not being saved. do you have an idea why?

Comment: Have you checked the console when you're posting the form? Do you see any error? If no, how about inspecting your request under the Network tab, check that you're sending the image daa

Comment: @WillKeeling I have checked the network tab. have also checked my `request.FILES` and it containes the image

Comment: @WillKeeling this the `request.FILES` which contains the new image: `<MultiValueDict: {'img_data': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: apple-20clip-20art-nicubunu_Apple_Clipart_Free.png (image/png)>]}>`

Comment: @WillKeeling what does `InMemoryUploaded` mean here?

Answer (score 0):

finally after about 5 days, I found out where the problem was. 
In my model I had the field "image". but in my ajax call i had named it "img_data". that is why it was not being saved.

this question helped me find out:
[Save method of Django model's instance does not update fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267128/save-method-of-django-models-instance-does-not-update-fields)