# Save method of Django model does not update fields of existing record even if force update

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-models, save

I am trying to update the record that already exists in the database and therefore I use this code

```
        if 'supplierId' not in req.keys():
            return JsonResponse({'code': 0, 'msg': "supplier was not selected", 'result': ''}, safe=False)

        assigneeId = User.objects.get(pk=req.get('assigneeId', 1))
        responsibleId = User.objects.get(pk=req.get('responsibleId', 1))
        redistributionMethod = req.get('redistributionMethod', 0)
        amount = req.get('allCost', 0)

        procurement_doc = ProcurementDocJournal.objects.get(id=pk)
        print(procurement_doc)
          procurement_doc.docType = req['docType']
        procurement_doc.status = req['status']
        procurement_doc.companyId = Company.objects.get(pk=req['companyId'])
        procurement_doc.datetime = req['datetime']
        procurement_doc.supplierId = Partner.objects.get(pk=req['supplierId'])
        procurement_doc.assigneeId = assigneeId
        procurement_doc.warehouseId = Warehouse.objects.get(pk=req['warehouseId'])
        procurement_doc.responsibleId = responsibleId
        procurement_doc.redistributionMethod = redistributionMethod
        procurement_doc.amount = amount
        procurement_doc.comment = req['comment']
        procurement_doc.save(force_update=True, update_fields=['comment', 'amount', 'redistributionMethod',
                                                               'responsibleId', 'warehouseId',
                                                               'supplierId', 'datetime',
                                                               'companyId', 'assigneeId', 'status', 'docType'])
```

where req contains a request
something like this

```
{
    'docType': 3,
    'status': 1,
    'companyId': '2',
    'warehouseId': '3',
    'assigneeId': '5',
    'supplierId': '12671',
    'responsibleId': '5',
    'datetime': '2020-04-01 08:01:00',
    'comment': ''
}
```

As you can see there is a print which assures me that I selected the correct row

when I noticed that these records are not updated I searched for causes and found

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267128/save-method-of-django-models-instance-does-not-update-fields) question where the guy who asked says *The message field was missing from the model definition*
in my case, none of these are missing from the model's description

```
class ProcurementDocJournal(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    docNumber = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
    docType = models.IntegerField()
    depended = models.IntegerField()
    companyId = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  db_column='companyId')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    currencyId = models.ForeignKey(Currency, db_column='currencyId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currencyRate = models.FloatField()
    redistributionMethod = models.IntegerField()
    assigneeId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ProcurementDocJournal',
                                   db_column='assigneeId')
    warehouseId = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    db_column='warehouseId')
    responsibleId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ProcurementDoc',
                                      db_column='responsibleId')
    supplierId = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   db_column='supplierId')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    comment = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'procurementDocJournal'
        get_latest_by = 'id'
```

**Edit**
I have an action that contains

```
        procurement_doc_journal_item = ProcurementDocJournal.objects.get(id=pk)
        currencyId = req['currency']
        currency = Currency.objects.get(id=currencyId)
        currencyRate = CurrencyRate(date, currency.name)

        procurement_doc_journal_item.currencyId = currency
        procurement_doc_journal_item.currencyRate = currencyRate['rate']
        procurement_doc_journal_item.save()
```

and works like a charm

there is no any error that logs say

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if there's any error in your logs. I'd kind of expect to see something since if it's not saving, it must be bombing out before that as no fields are mandatory.

I am, however, not sure you're setting your FKs correctly here:

```
procurement_doc.companyId = Company(req['companyId'])
```

Should be

```
procurement_doc.companyId = Company.objects.get(pk=req['companyId'])
```

and that assumes `companyId` is set to a value that exists of course ... Whether this is the source of your issue or not, I'm not sure. I don't see any of your FKs are mandatory.

Edit: I've just tested this on one of my models with a simple `id` key:

```
>>> Contact(1)
Contact()
>>> c = Contact(1)
>>> c.name
''
>>> c = Contact.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> c.name
'Mike'
```

It really doesn't seem to me as though it works ...

**Sidenote:** You can simplify code like this:

```
    if 'allCost' not in req.keys():
        amount = 0
    else:
        amount = req['allCost']
```

By doing:

```
amount = req.get('allCost', 0)
```

Comment: thanks for suggestions and it does not return any errors. I am going to change this staff as you suggested and return in a moment. about procurement_doc.companyId = Company(req['companyId'])  i have similar uses across 10K code in every other case it works

Comment: I've just tested this on one of my projects in the django shell. Doesn't seem to me as though it works, so not sure exactly what you're doing that I'm not?

Comment: i have edited as you suggested c = Contact.objects.get(pk=1) I mean this  but nothing 
I Have another piece of code which works

Comment: I believe you - just not sure what we're doing differently :) I guess it makes no difference for you? Maybe output the `procurement_doc` just prior to save? My only guess is that it thinks no data hhas changed, and so does not waste the DB hit on an update ...

Comment: i think the same but data changes almost every time I also asked for force update but nothing

Comment: OK  - don't want a prolonged discussion here in comments, but maybe put that `print` statement in prior to `save` and see if anythibg has changed and update your question with the details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222394/discussion-between-giorgi-beria-and-urbanespaceman).